# regex in parentheses

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
(20% up)
```

I want to extract `20`

I've tried `\(([^%]+)\)`

But can't get the value alone.

Comment: You'll have to escape the outer parenthesis with a preceding backslash presumably.  In addition you'll want to inspect the first capture group, not the entire match

Comment: `\([^()]*?(\d+)[^()]*\)`, see https://regex101.com/r/MlcIMg/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I have (20% up) (30 up) (50 up) but I just want to get the value of the one with the % and not the others.  How should I add it to that regex?

Comment: You might use `(?<=\()\d+(?=%[^()]*\))` then, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MlcIMg/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\()\d+(?=%[^()]*\))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MlcIMg/2).

**Details**

- `(?<=\()` - a `(` must appear immediately on the left
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=%[^()]*\))` - a `%` and any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` followed with `)` must appear immediately on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you might do it in java.

- `(\\d+)` captures the 20
- If you specifically want to focus on that followed by a space and `up` you can put those in after the `%` sign. e.g ( `(\\d+)% up` )

```
String s = "(20% up)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)%").matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints

```
20
```

Comment: Thanks.  This returns the number followed by the % sign.  I want to isolate the number from the %.  Not sure how to do that using regex.

Comment: Are you certain  you entered it correctly?  When I do this it just returns the number.  The % sign is not part of the capture.  Only the shaded part is the regex.  The other is part of the sentence structure. So  the regex should be `(\\d+)% up`